# print time of javascript using loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I stuck until here, I got infinite loop when I proceed. Below code is a half way, how to print from 1:00 AM to 12: AM.

http://jsfiddle.net/sychhLya/

JS

```
$(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        var time = '<p>' + i + ':00 AM</p>';
        $('.holder').append(time);
    }
});
```

Comment: show me the code which call this function

Comment: This is too vague. Can you further explain what you need?

Comment: Other than outputting `0:00` to start your demo works fine. There is no problem here that can be replicated

Comment: Other than to move the `var` outside the loop, (`{..}` does not have scope in _JavaScript_) and cache your `$('.holder')`, there are no problems with posted code or demo fiddle

Comment: @Stephn_R print 1am until 12 am

Comment: @PaulS. it's not completed, it's 50% done only

Comment: @JamesLemon what's stopping you from changing the initial conditions of the `for` loop?

Comment: @PaulS. I have some problem getting the decrements, should it be within the first loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
$(function() {
  for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    var time = '<p>' + i + ':00 AM</p>';
    $('.holder').append(time);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="holder"></p>
```

Or this?

```js
$(function() {
  for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 60; j++) {
      j = ("0" + j).slice(-2);
      var time = '<p>' + i + ':' + j + ' AM</p>';
      $('.holder').append(time);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="holder"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using the Date class in Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    var x = new Date("March 3, 2015 01:00");
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
       $('.holder').append(x.getHours() + ":" + x.getMinutes() + x.getSeconds() + "AM<br/>");
       x.setHours(x.getHours()+1);
       console.log(x);
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sychhLya/3/