# infinite loop concatenation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I want to insert 12AM to 11PM to a select tag but in my loop 2 things are missing, 12AM and 12PM.

```
            for (i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
                var am = '<option>' + i + ':00 AM</option>';
                $('#time').append(am);
            }

            for (i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
                var pm = '<option>' + i + ':00 PM</option>';
                $('#time').append(pm);
            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mzswo9xt/

Comment: Your loop condition is that `i < 12`, so of course it never gets to 12! Use `i <= 12`...

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie I want to 12 AM to be at the top

Comment: You just got answers in the last question you asked that give you the proper output  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845202/print-time-of-javascript-using-loop  Don't you even look at those answers before asking a new question?

Comment: @charlietfl because I asked it wrongly :(

Comment: Well don't start a new question , ask for clarification on the prior one. Now you have just ignored people trying to help you

Comment: @charlietfl sorry for that, now this question is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function convert24HourTo12Hour(h) {
   return (h + 11) % 12 + 1;
}

for (i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
   $('#time').append(
      '<option>' + convert24HourTo12Hour(i) + ':00 ' + (i < 12 ? 'A' : 'P') + 'M</option>'
   );
}
```

The `(i + 11) % 12 + 1` part converts 0 to 12, and 13-23 to 1-11.

The next set of parentheses is a "conditional expression" and selects `A` or `P` depending on the value of `i`.

Comment: To me it's dead simple. I converted the hard part to a function for you so it can be somewhat self-documenting.

Answer (score 0):

In the first loop,

```
for (i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
```

should be:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
```

That middle bit is the continuation condition and, in your variant, it continued only while the hour was *less* than twelve, in other words, one through eleven inclusive.

---

If you really want midnight as the first entry, you have to treat it specially, something like:

```
var opt = '<option>12:00 midnight</option>';
$('#time').append(opt);

for (i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
    opt = '<option>' + i + ':00 AM</option>';
    $('#time').append(opt);
}

opt = '<option>12:00 noon</option>';
$('#time').append(opt);

for (i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
    opt = '<option>' + i + ':00 PM</option>';
    $('#time').append(opt);
}
```

noticing that I've replaced the erroneous 12am/pm with "proper" designations - you may not agree with that stance but I think it's preferable. If you want to use the original designations that you had, just change the text.

You may also want to consider the shorter:

```
$('#time').append('<option>12:00 midnight</option>');
for (i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
    $('#time').append('<option>' + i + ':00 AM</option>');
}
$('#time').append('<option>12:00 noon</option>');
for (i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
    $('#time').append('<option>' + i + ':00 PM</option>');
}
```

since you're not actually *needing* to keep `opt` around other than for setting the content.

---

And I'd be remiss in not mentioning that, if you're going to be working a lot some some aspect (such as dates and times), it might be worthwhile finding something that makes your life easier, such as [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/). This will greatly ease effort expended with dates and times in general, *and* it comes with formatting so you could simply use something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    var m = new moment(new Date(2015,0,1,i,0,0));
    $('#time').append(m.format("<option>h:00 A</option>"));
}
```

though that reverts to what I consider erroneous behaviour re noon/midnight.

Comment: how to put the 12:00 AM at the top?

Comment: ah just prepend? I thought it can be done more neat within the loop haha.